# Volume of a solid generated by $y=x^2$ and $x=4$

Tags: calculus, solid-of-revolution

Find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region bounded by the graphs about the line $x=6$.

The graphs are $$y=x^2$$ $$x=4$$
Setting up the integral using the shell method gives the equation
$$2\pi \int_0^{16}\left(6-x^2\right)\left(2 \right)dx$$

After multiplying out we get
$$2\pi \int_0^{16}12-2x^2 dx$$
I haven't integrated yet because I wanna make sure I have the correct integral first. The way I understand it is, you take the graph you're revolving  and subtract it from the line you're revolving around. This being the axis of rotation.

In this case it would be $6-x^2$. Then doing the same for $x=4$, this being $2$ from, $6-4$.

Am I correct in my understanding, is there an easier way to think of this and if I am wrong how much of this do I have wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using cylindrical shell method

$$2\pi \int_0^4\left(6-x\right)\left(x^2 \right)dx=128\pi $$

Comment: Hey Mohammad, I have edited the original question to fit a different, but similar one. If you want to remove your answer I understand as it might confuse new eyes.

Comment: @EricBrown   check my new answer please.